# Callback help to get message string from AWS Data using Node

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am using Node.Js with aws-sdk to populate `var message`. 
1) First I call a function to get AWS Groups - which I then concatenate to message.
2) Second I call another function based off a data from the first function - which I then concatenate to message.
Last I sending an email and using message string.
**Question**: How can I concatenate the string `message` and pass it to function SendEmail?

Here is my code.

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({region: 'us-east-1'});
var iam = new aws.IAM({apiVersion: '2010-05-08'});

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    console.log("Incoming: ", event);
    var message = "";

    function AwsListGroupsFunction(err, data) 
    {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else
        {
            //Get AWS Groups from AWS Account
            var dataCount = data.Groups.length-1;
            for (var key in data.Groups) 
            {
                message+= data.Groups[key].GroupName
                // Then get all users associated to the GroupName
                var groupParams = { GroupName: data.Groups[key].GroupName};
                iam.getGroup(groupParams, AwsGetGroupFunction); // end of else for if iam.getGroup

                if (key != dataCount)
                    message += ', ';
            }
        }
        return message;
    };

    function AwsGetGroupFunction(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else{
            // successful response
            message+= "<br/>";
            for (var userKey in data.Users) {
                message += data.Users[userKey].UserName + ' and PasswordLastUsed: ' + data.Users[userKey].PasswordLastUsed + ' , ';
            }                      

        }
        return message;
    };

    function SendEmail(message){
   console.log('===SENDING EMAIL HERE using message variable===');

    }


    // This is the only function called which calls other functions
    var params = {};  
    iam.listGroups(params, AwsListGroupsFunction);

};
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I added it to the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AwsListGroupsFunction(err, data) function is used as callback for  iam.listGroups. So you cannot return value from AwsListGroupsFunction function in this context. So is for other callback function.

You could solve this in many ways, async library methods like mapSeries would be better choice.Here is a pseudo code for a simple solution. You could improve it through further refactoring.

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({region: 'us-east-1'});
var iam = new aws.IAM({apiVersion: '2010-05-08'});
var async = require('async');

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    console.log("Incoming: ", event);
    var message = "";

    function AwsListGroupsFunction(err, data) 
    {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else
        {
            //Get AWS Groups from AWS Account
            var dataCount = data.Groups.length-1;
            async.mapSeries(data.Groups, function(group, cb) {
              var partialMessage = group.GroupName;
              // Then get all users associated to the GroupName
              var groupParams = { GroupName: group.GroupName};
              iam.getGroup(groupParams, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                  cb(err, "");
                } 
                else{
                    // successful response
                    partialMessage+= "<br/>";
                    for (var userKey in data.Users) {
                      partialMessage += data.Users[userKey].UserName + ' and PasswordLastUsed: ' + data.Users[userKey].PasswordLastUsed + ' , ';
                    }                      
                    cb(null, partialMessage);
                }
              });
            }, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                  //handle error. Expected message is not ready
                }
                else {
                  /*
                    Here result contains array of partial messages; ie [partial message for group1, partial message for group2, ...]
                    concatinate partial messages and send email.
                  */

                }
            });
        }

    };

    function SendEmail(message){
   console.log('===SENDING EMAIL HERE using message variable===');

    }

    // This is the only function called which calls other functions
    var params = {};  
    iam.listGroups(params, AwsListGroupsFunction);
};
```

Comment: That wont work. AwsListGroupsFunction Gets the Group Names such as "Group1", "Group2", then AwsGetGroupFunction gets the users associated to those groups above. I need to format my message like this
**Group1**
  -User1, User2, User3
**Group2**
  -User1, User2, User3

So I have to wait until AwsGetGroupFunction is done concatenating the string